# Why doesn't assigning variables inside a function copy instead of referencing it

Tags: javascript, closures, lexical-scope

I have this code:

```
function makeArmy() {
  let shooters = [];

  let i = 0;
  while (i < 10) {
    let shooter = function () {
      console.log(i);
      // that should show its number
    };
    shooters.push(shooter); // and add it to the array
    i++;
  }

  // ...and return the array of shooters
  return shooters;
}

let army = makeArmy();

// all shooters show 10 instead of their numbers 0, 1, 2, 3...
army[0](); // 10 from the shooter number 0
army[1](); // 10 from the shooter number 1
army[2](); // 10 ...and so on.
```

This happens because `i` is always a reference to the outer `i` inside the `makeArmy()` function.

If we adjust the code to be:

```
function makeArmy() {
  let shooters = [];

  let i = 0;
  while (i < 10) {
    // copy the varible i into the while lexical scope
    let j = i
    let shooter = function () {
      console.log(j);
      // that should show its number
    };
    shooters.push(shooter); // and add it to the array
    i++;
  }

  // ...and return the array of shooters
  return shooters;
}

let army = makeArmy();


army[0](); // 0
army[1](); // 1
army[2](); // 2
```

The above code works as expected because instead of referencing the variable `i` inside `shooter()` we are copying it into `j`, thus making it available to the shooter function in its own scope.

Now, my question is, why doesn't copying the `i` variable inside the function itself work? even though I'm effectively still copying the variable? What am I missing here?

Code:

```
function makeArmy() {
  let shooters = [];

  let i = 0;
  while (i < 10) {
    let shooter = function () {
      let j = i;

      console.log(j);
      // that should show its number
    };
    shooters.push(shooter); // and add it to the array
    i++;
  }

  // ...and return the array of shooters
  return shooters;
}

let army = makeArmy();

// all shooters show 10 instead of their numbers 0, 1, 2, 3...
army[0](); // 10 from the shooter number 0
army[1](); // 10 from the shooter number 1
army[2](); // 10 ...and so on.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are copying at a time at which `i` is already `10`.

In fact, with `let j = i` in the *inner* function, there will be no difference to using `i` directly, because that assignment also executes only when you invoke that inner function, and as said, at this point `i` will already be `10`, since the invocation happens long after the loop completed, in e.g. `army[0]()`.

As you noted, it works if you move the `let j = i` outside of the inner function (but still inside the loop). This way, the assigment to the local variable(s) `j` happens on each iteration immediately, and the inner function later refers to those 10 different `j`'s with their right values that were previously set at that point in time when `i` had the respective value that you wanted.

---

By the way, this problem won't exist if you'd use a `for` loop instead because `for` with `let` has some "magic" that creates a semi-separated scope for each iteration (the exact way this works is [a bit more complicated](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nzokr6Boeaw)).

```js
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    let shooter = function () {
      console.log(i);
    };
    shooters.push(shooter);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `console.log(i)` in your shooter function `i`'s value refers to the one that has once the while loop ended, thus i would be the last value it had. In your case `i`'s value changes over time, showing the last value it had. When you assign that to a variable (`let j = i`) you copy that value and not the reference so it gives you the result you want.

Comment: so why does it print the latest `i` value only?

Comment: Because it is the last value that variable was modified to